# Naive logic on which mathematics should be relevant to physics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, cardinals

### Background

So I am under the impression that there is no physical theory which makes use of any kind of mathematics which has a set of solution space greater than the cardinality of the real numbers.

My reasoning is as follows:

The experimentalist has to measure this theory. The set of solutions when continuous is (or part of a) real number line.

Any theory must have a solution space which can be mapped to experiment. Hence, the cardinality must be the same.

### Question

Is there an exception I have not heard of? Is the above reasoning correct? I'm sure there are mathematics which work in larger cardinalities and while mathematicians may not mind if their work meets physics (I'm sure it's a delight when it does), does such mathematics find application?

P.S: I use the word "naive" as I don't think that our imagination exceeds that of the universe.

Comment: Could you phrase "...which has a set of solution space greater..." differently? Or provide a hypothetical example of what you mean by this question?

Comment: What about *anything* related to wave functions making use of the complex plane?

Comment: @merkh it's slightly difficult to do because while I can think of an example that example would automatically limit the scope of this question. Please give me some time so I can think clearer on how to phrase this?

Comment: @klagen the measurement enables one to map from complex to real with a probability of the event.

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Without reading the words too closely, it seems like you are asking if there are physical theories where within that theory, Alice asks Bob a question, and Bob provides an answer which belongs to a mathematical space that is larger than the real (or complex numbers for that matter).  Is that entirely nonsense or getting closer?

Comment: Well in any physical theory there is essentially only freedom of the initial conditions. Now when Alice asks a question say what is the position of the electron .. Bob due to quantum mechanics can tell her a probability distribution at best ... And there automatically this interpretation of the question is falsified ... Lemme just say thats what I'm definitely not taking about.

Comment: Conceivably it might happen. The possibility of the existence of some wave-function might be shown to depend on the existence of some subset of $\Bbb N$ with certain properties. E.g. the existence of a measurable cardinal implies the existence of a thing called $ O^#$ (Oh-Sharp). The existence of $O^# $ (i) is equivalent to the existence of a certain kind of subset of $\Bbb N,$ and (ii) implies the consistency of a proper class of inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet interesting... Maybe you can write that as an answer and I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceivably it might happen. The possibility of the existence of some wave-function might be shown to depend on the existence of some subset of N with certain properties. E.g. the existence of a measurable cardinal implies the existence of a thing called $O$^#
 (Oh-Sharp). The existence of $O$^# (i) is equivalent to the existence of a certain kind of subset of N, and (ii) implies the consistency of a proper class of inaccessible cardinals.